# Home button stuck, iTunes won't recognize iPhone and I need to restore?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

- My iPhone is out of warranty
- I jailbroke it the moment an iOS 8.1.x jailbreak came out
- A tweak which was updated broke something
- It's stuck at the Apple screen
- The home button is broken
- iTunes doesn't recognize it.

Help?

Note: Pressing Volume Up for safe mode doesn't work either.

Comment: Can someone please help? I'd much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Woah dude. You are in a mess! Unfortunately, you cannot get it into restore mode without that home button working. What I think you should do is if you are brave enough is to buy a cheap repair kit online and attempt to fix your button. If it doesn't work, no harm done cause its out of warranty! Go for it man and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following that helped me fix my homebutton thing on my iPhone 4. But WARNING - it only fixes MECHANICAL issues, not software issues! If this is not your case or your button is really physically broken, don't try this at home and downvote me! :-)

1. Switch off the phone and pull out your SIM card.
2. Buy medical alcohol in a pharmacy with a very high percentage, at least 97% (in Germany it is called Isopropanol or Isopropyl alcohol).
3. Take a pipette and drop a few drops onto the home button, so the button is completely covered in it.
4. Press and release the button at least 50 times, starting slow and increasing speed.
5. Add more alcohol, but less and carefully, only a few drops! don't drain your phone!
6. Start pressing and releasing again at least another 50 times.
7. It should be very easy now to press the button.
8. Let the iPhone dry and recover for at least 8h.
9. Put in again your SIM card and power on the phone.
10. Feel happy with a recovered home button. :-)

After your home button is working again, try again your previous steps for recovering your phone.